# How to write xpath for this particular webelement which has a double quotes?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, xpath-1.0

I identified one unique webelement as:

```
ng-click="navigateToNewCustomer('New Customer')"
```

How can I write xpath for this? When i wrote xpath it throws error since I am using double quotes.

```
//*[@ng-click="navigateToNewCustomer('New Customer')"].click();
```

Comment: Please add HTML snip for WebElement you identified and error traceback with your code trials

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can escape double quotes with a backslash:
`//*[@ng-click=\"navigateToNewCustomer('New Customer')\"].click();`